# Pass ssh key using jclouds in openstack

Tags: ssh, openstack, jclouds

I used jclouds to create a server in openstack. Although I am able to create the server, I also want to pass my public ssh key in order to connect to the server after cloud init is finished. Below is my code.

```
package org.chris.jcloud;

import static com.google.common.io.Closeables.closeQuietly;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import org.jclouds.ContextBuilder;
import org.jclouds.compute.ComputeService;
import org.jclouds.compute.ComputeServiceContext;
import org.jclouds.compute.domain.NodeMetadata;
import org.jclouds.compute.domain.TemplateBuilder;
import org.jclouds.compute.options.RunScriptOptions;
import org.jclouds.io.Payloads;
import org.jclouds.logging.slf4j.config.SLF4JLoggingModule;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaAsyncApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.Server;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.ServerCreated;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.features.ServerApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.options.CreateServerOptions;
import org.jclouds.predicates.SocketOpen;
import org.jclouds.rest.RestContext;
import org.jclouds.scriptbuilder.ScriptBuilder;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.inject.Module;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.io.Closeables;
import com.google.common.net.HostAndPort;

import org.jclouds.compute.RunNodesException;
import org.jclouds.compute.domain.Template;
import org.jclouds.scriptbuilder.domain.OsFamily;
import org.jclouds.sshj.config.SshjSshClientModule;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;
import static org.jclouds.compute.config.ComputeServiceProperties.POLL_INITIAL_PERIOD;
import static org.jclouds.compute.config.ComputeServiceProperties.POLL_MAX_PERIOD;
import static org.jclouds.compute.options.TemplateOptions.Builder.authorizePublicKey;

public  class JClouds implements Closeable {
   private ComputeService compute;
   private RestContext<NovaApi, NovaAsyncApi> nova;
   private Set<String> zones;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      JClouds jCloudsNova = new JClouds();

      try {
         jCloudsNova.init();
         jCloudsNova.listServers();
         jCloudsNova.close();
         jCloudsNova.createServers();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally {
         jCloudsNova.close();
      }
   }

   private void init() {
      Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new SLF4JLoggingModule());

      String provider = "openstack-nova";
      String identity = "admin:admin"; // tenantName:userName
      String password = "test"; // demo account uses ADMIN_PASSWORD too

      ComputeServiceContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
            .endpoint("http://192.168.1.33:5000/v2.0/")
            .credentials(identity, password)
            .modules(modules)
            .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);
      compute = context.getComputeService();
      nova = context.unwrap();
      zones = nova.getApi().getConfiguredZones();
   }

   private void listServers() {
      for (String zone: zones) {
         ServerApi serverApi = nova.getApi().getServerApiForZone(zone);

         System.out.println("Servers in " + zone);

         for (Server server: serverApi.listInDetail().concat()) {
            System.out.println("  " + server);
         }
      }
   }

   private void createServers() {
    for (String zone : zones) {
        ServerApi serverApi = nova.getApi().getServerApiForZone(zone);
        CreateServerOptions sv = CreateServerOptions.Builder.adminPass("test");
        ServerCreated newServer = serverApi.create("paparia", "ab8fbee6-4907-4e59-ba77-471362bc8200", "1", sv);
    //  TemplateBuilder templateBuilder = compute.templateBuilder();
    //  Template template = templateBuilder.options(authorizePublicKey(Payloads.newPayload(new File("/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")).toString())).build();


        System.out.println("Servers in " + zone);
        listServers();
    }
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



   /*public void close() {
      closeQuietly(compute.getContext());
   }*/
}
```

Comment: From what I can see, it looks like the template is commented out that would add the public key. Second, the template needs to get used during your create call. [`createNodesInGroup` will take that template you built](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/f5f038cc4c92c85fb8bc61c7ca8a591b7b2dacad/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudservers/CreateServer.java#L97-L106).

Answer (score 1):

I dunno, how you can specify a new key during client runtime, but to use a predefined public key, previously uploaded to Openstack, use method

```
CreateServerOptions.Builder.keyPairName(KEY_NAME)
```

The list of public keys is available in the Openstack dashboard at "Access & Security" > "Keypairs". I'm actually not sure, if you can specify a new key for an instance, since the dashboard form for a manual instance creation doesn't support new key uploading. It's got an import of a new NAMED key instead though, which is added to the list of public keys mentioned above, after the instance is created.